# Loop cut & Slide cutting through

Tags: sculpting

[image][image]I work in cancer research and I want to illustrate a multi-leaf collimator for a conference.

I was using loop cut and slide to create the independent slabs from a block, and they look good. But unfortunately they are not independent, so I can't move them. Watch 5 seconds of this video to get the idea of what a multi-leaf collimator is: https://youtu.be/eZS6DVGBx0k?t=115

Anybody can give some advice? The real challenge is to create them simultaneously so they are all of the same width.

Comment: Please add some images to your question to illustrate your points.

Comment: I should have been clearer, I meant images of what you already have in blender.

Comment: I think you should do it they way it is in the video. Those are each seperate thin squares copy and pasted next to each other. You wont be able to animate it the way you have it (one piece).

Comment: oh wow. Good thing I have time to do this. Thanks.

Comment: Why not create a single leaf and use array modifier?

Comment: @Denis thanks. I think array modifier is what I was looking for.

Comment: Be careful with array modifier, you wont be able to animate the middle. Read my answer.

Comment: I'm able to create this with Animation Nodes but... I don't know how to gave a hole a custom shape, so besides it's efficient it's kind a useless. I can't force it to interpolate as I want trough the curve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just create a few thin squares that you want to animate and copy/paste (shift + D) them side by side.

Be careful with an array modifier because you wont be able to animate the middle part. I would just use an array modifier for the end parts to fill the screen.
[image]

The non moving parts are an array modifier. The animated parts are seperate squares (leafs).

Comment: Thanks. By the way, this is what it looks like after finished. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t3M4pRCngus

Answer (score 0):

You can use Shape keys to animate.
[image]

Comment: I think this could do with some information as to *how* they make shape keys to do this.